# Can the functions exist?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

For any a and b(both positive integers not equal to each other), can functions having the below properties exist? If no, why not?

f(a,b) = Z

g(a) = Z

h(b) = Z

Z is the common output of all these functions. Please also note that for each unique pair of (a,b) we get a unique Z.

More generally,

f(a,b,c,..) = Z

g(a) = Z

h(b) = Z

i(c) = Z

...

...

I am not a mathematician and I don't really know which tags should be used in this question so please pardon me if you see this question or its tags as irrelevant.

Comment: What is a "variable constant"?

Comment: All functions with the property that $g(a) = h(b)$ for all $a$ and $b$ are constant.

Comment: @NoahSchweber I've done some edits

Comment: @eyeballfrog I've done some edits

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No you can’t.

If you take a pair of values $(a_0,b_0)$ then $f(a_0,b_0) = g(a_0)$ now if you change the value of b $(a_0,b_1)$ then $f(a_0,b_1) \ne f(a_0,b_0)$ by your requirement for unique values.

But since $f(a_0,b_1) = g(a_0)$ then $g(a_0) \ne g(a_0)$ which is absurd.

Basically since g and h have no knowledge of the other parameter to f there is no way it can change according to it.

Comment: I knew I was missing something basic.. Thanks a lot for answering